# JFactory::getUser() giving odd results

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm creating a extension that involves checking for a users id. Basically i run a potential username through `JFactory::getUser();` as in example 2 [here](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getUser). My code is

```
$user_id=&JFactory::getUser($name);
if($user_id->id==0) {      //Line 79
  $profile_link = $name;
} else {    
  $profile_link = '<a href="'.JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=userProfile&user='.$user_id->id).'">' . $name . '</a>';
}
echo $profile_link;
```

Just for clarification I've just selected out the relevant part of the code. As you can see if the username is a valid user then I link to their community builder profile. Else I just echo out the name (this is being run through a foreach loop of a list of names).

I'm running into 2 issues - that don't seem to be expected.

1. Firstly if the name doesn't exist. Joomla is posting this up as an error in the system messages area.

   `JUser: :_load: User xxxx does not exist`

There is also a php error of (note I've pointed out line 79 in the code above)

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in MODULEROOT/tmpl/default.php on line 79
```

1. Secondly if a user is logged out then whether the name is valid or not Joomla finds `$user_id->id` to be 0. This is despite the documentation clearly stating this should run `regardless of the status of the current user`

Can anybody see anything wrong with this code? Or else know if the standards of `JFactory::getUser()` have changed since that documentation was written for Joomla 2.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario what you can do is rather than using Joomla in-built functions you can make a SQL query(DB Call) which retrieves the user data.

EG :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'xxx';
```

If the query returned results you can you can go on linking the profile, otherwise you can echo an error message.

This will automatically solve the 2nd issue you have too.

If you have any issues let me know.

Comment: Would rather use native Joomla commands if possible - although you make a very valid point and will probably revert to this if I can't find out why `JFactory::getUser();` is failing. Thanks!

Comment: I know using native functions are good but in this scenario above method would help you out

Comment: As nothing else is coming on this question accepted it. Your answer is definately valid :) Submitted a Bug report here tho http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=29986 to get some clarification on what the expected result should be!

Answer (score 2):

If you check JFactory class, in %joomlaFolder%/libraries/joomla/factory.php the method getUser($id = null) (line 210, for me) use JUser inside, seems that the problem comes when obtain a current  sesion, then, you can use directly the [JUser](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/User/JUser.html) method getInstance instead of [JFactory::getUser](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/JFactory.html#getUser), and you code will be change like this

Before:

```
$user_id=&JFactory::getUser($name);
```

After:

```
$user_id=&JUser::getInstance($name);
```

As both return JUser object, the rest of the code remain same.